# Get Multiple rows in SQL Query

Tags: mysql

I'm using a SQL query in JDBC. It is supposed to get:

1- **post_id** (from *table wp_posts*) **WHERE post_type = product** 
2- **post_title** (from *table wp_posts*) **WHERE post_type = product** 
3- **meta_value** from *table wp_postmeta* **WHERE (wp_posts.post_id = wp_postmeta.post_id) AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = _stock_status, total_sales, _regular_price, _sale_price, _price, _stock**

(from specified META_KEYs from *table WP_POSTMETA* corresponding to my POST_IDs from *table WP_POSTS*)

Basically, I'm working on getting WooCommerce product details from WP Database.

This is the code my friend has helped me with so far:

```
SELECT  wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title,wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM    wp_posts, wp_postmeta WHERE (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key='_stock')
```

Just like it is getting _stock at the end of the query, I want to get 5 more items (_stock_status, total_sales, _regular_price, _sale_price, _price) for each POST_ID
[image: Details I need to get from wp_postmeta]

EDIT:
My friend helped me with another query, but it is not getting the information in a single array, instead it makes different array items for each piece of information.

```
SELECT  wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title,wp_postmeta.meta_key,wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM   wp_posts, wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id HAVING wp_postmeta.meta_key='_stock' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key='_stock_status' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key='total_sales' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key='_regular_price' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key='_sale_price' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key='_price'
```

I want the results to come out in a single 2D array.

Comment: I don't know why people keep down voting my question.

Perhaps they could leave a comment as to why they don't like my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps some sample data in tables, and desired results. Which is pretty evident in the comments under my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This select statement below follows the question that wants to include additional meta_key information (not just "_stock"). Change accordingly, as only you have your data.

The OP clearly has typos in this sentence "wp_postmeta.meta_key = _stock_status, total_sales, _reulgar_price, _sale_price, _price, _stock" as well as that query that his "friend" wrote.

```
SELECT  p.ID, p.post_title,m.meta_value 
FROM wp_posts p
join  wp_postmeta m
on p.ID=m.post_id
AND m.meta_key in ('_stock','_stock_status','total_sales','_regular_price','_sale_price','_price')
```

Comment: Its not working in the sequence I want.. I have 182 matching POST_IDs but yours have made 1895 array items. I want the results in a 2-dimension array.

Comment: hopefully that is better, @KevinBrown

Comment: your scripts runs fine. Just that after 182 entries with _stock, it starts again from 1st entry for _stock_status, then after another 182 it starts again for total_sales... and so on. Can we not get all of the items in a single 2D-Array?

Comment: I don't have your data. perhaps you want it to be `select distinct  p.post_title,m.meta_value`, or `select distinct p.post_title` or `select distinct p.ID,p.post_title` ... who knows but you

Comment: Okay, I will accept your answer. Apparently, the only difference between your solution and my friend's 2nd solution is that your query gets detail_A for all items then gets detail_B for all items and so on.. while his query gets detail_A then detail_B and so on for 1 item, then moves to the 2nd.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to manipulate the results myself to form a 2D array that has all the details (A,B,C) for an item in a single array item.

Comment: I don't comprehend how the term `array` even factors into this question. We aren't talking anything but raw mysql commands at the moment. Unless I am missing something

Comment: I am a noob, I previously had formed a script where the query was returning post_id & post_title for mathing post_types. That script gave the output in a 2D array. I understand the final output is not a part of this question so hence your answer is correct. Thank you for your answer! :)